# How can a child route (or resource) access a parent resource's model from within the model hook?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Seems like in the case of nested routes, each route's `model` hook is called before any of the `setupController` hooks are called. So how can a child route safely access the parent's model?

In my case, the models aren't actually persisting entities. They're both generated, based on the params, in the model hooks. So I wouldn't think a `Parent.find()` / ajax / promise seems like the way to go. Ideally, the parent model should be accessible through the `ParentController`, no? Or is this approach not in keeping with best practices?

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("parent", { path: "parent/:name" }, function() {
    this.route('child');
  });
});

App.ParentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    // build a model here, based on params.
    // no asynch stuff happening, should be good to go.
    return { lastName: params.name }
  },

  setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
});

App.ChildRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    parentModel = this.controllerFor('parent').get('model');
    return {lastName: parentModel.get('name') + 'son' };

    // parent Model is null
    // need the parent model HERE, 
    // but I can't get it through the controller yet
    // as setupController in the parent route hasn't been called yet
  }
});
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

modelFor

How'd I miss that?

```
App.ChildRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    parentModel = this.modelFor('parent');
    return {lastName: parentModel.get('name') + 'son' };
  }
});
```

Comment: Gotta love it when you can answer your own question.

Comment: Thanks @doublea. I'd like to further clarify that the argument you pass to `modelFor` is the name of the parent route whose model you would like. E.g. `user`, `user.posts`, etc. And [here are the docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor).

Comment: Thank you so much @steve.hanson, I was doing it with upper camel case, and not with dot notation!!

Comment: In my case, the `modelFor` approach only worked when I specified the ***route*** whose model I wanted, like `let account = this.modelFor('admin.accounts.edit');`

Answer (score 1):

doublea's answer still applies for Ember 3.x, with some slight changes to the boilerplate syntax of the route. Also the `get` is no longer necessary, but doesn't hurt anything to leave it there. Here's the 3.x syntax:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
    model(params) {
       parentModel = this.modelFor('parent');
       return {lastName: parentModel.name + 'son' };
    }
});
```

For Ember 2.16 through at least all of Ember 3, another way to get information about parent routes is using the [RouterService](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/RouterService/properties/currentRouteName?anchor=currentRouteName)

Methods like `currentRouteName` and `currentUrl` can be helpful for display, although it's best to avoid fancy string parsing when there are better options. You can also use the router service's `transitionTo` in order to change routes from a Component.

The Router Service can be used like this:

import {inject as service} from '@ember/service';

```
export default Component.extend({
    router: service(),
    actions: {
      clickedAThing() {
        this.router.transitionTo('some.route')
      }
    }
})
```